# To set text on spinner

Tags: android

I want to implement one code for three spinner where the user will fill there date of birth at register time when he/she will login and want to update there DOB, the DOB will pass on the spinner I have done it with day and month but there is one problem in year i.e adapter. adapter takes the (thisYear-18) year and print it but I want spinYear will take that value which I stored at registered time.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_details_fragment);
    Spinner spinDay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDay);
    Spinner spinMonth = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth);
    Spinner spinYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
    Button update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);

    Intent intent =getIntent();
     String str_DOB = intent.getStringExtra("dateofbirth");
    Log.e("DOB************",str_DOB);
    String[] d = str_DOB.split("-");
    Log.e("d[0]-------",d[0].toString());
    spinYear.setSelection (Integer.parseInt(d[0]));
    spinMonth.setSelection (Integer.parseInt(d[1]));
    spinDay.setSelection (Integer.parseInt(d[2]));
```

code for Year Adapter

```
    ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
    int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    thisYear=thisYear-18;
    for (int i = thisYear; i >= 1967; i--) {
        years.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, years);
    spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            final String yearName =  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().trim();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to set the selection of the year spinner based on your passed in Intent.

[`setSelection(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)) Takes the index of the item in the spinner you want to select.

After you call `setAdapter` do as so:

```
spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);

int index = years.indexOf(d[0]);
if (index != -1) {
    spinYear.setSelection(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the **year** in **onItemSelected()** method because this method get the position 0 and set it first.try to use below code:-

```
spinYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

if((d[2]).equals(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()))
{
            final String yearName =  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().trim();
}
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```